# Ресайз спрайтов в Unity2D

Tags: unity3d

у меня есть детализированный спрайт 900х900 пикселей, который должен занимать мало пространства на сцене. Как можно уменьшить его без сильной потери качества? Я пробовал менять localScale, pixels per unit, ресайзить в фш но это приводил к сильной потере качества.

Использую юнити LWRP ортографическую камеру.

Пример того что я хочу добиться:

Картинки существ сами по себе по идеивысокого качества и в игре они отображаются отлично
но при этом они уменьшены в несколько раз. Или например вертикальная колонка слева, где отображаются последние сыграные карты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: scale и ppu вообще не имеют ни какого отношения к качеству или весу изображения.

Comment: @Yaroslav первый комментарий довольно грубый. Просто дал бы запрос и все на этом, для чего стебать было?

Comment: @Andrew, одно дело вал новых людей, задающие базовые вопросы, часть из которых дети, особенно в теге `unity3d`. Но когда участник сообщества не способен написать простейший запрос, на который в интернетах бесчисленное количество статей, а не где-то там в документации... это осуждаемо. Судя по вопросу он даже не пытался что-то найти, сразу сюда. Вот и получил ответ... в соответствующей форме. Я не прав?

Comment: @Yaroslav Интересно слышать это от пользователя который даже не удосужился вникнуть в суть вопроса и тем не менее решил дать остроумный ответ не касающийся вопроса

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy, неправильно понял вопрос? Ок, извините. Andrew в своем ответе, тоже сомневается что понял его правильно. Как ты сформулировал, так люди и поймут. Что тут вообще делает скриншот hs? почему нет твоих скриншотов с наглядным примером того в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то тебя интересует использования канваса + изменение разрешения самого канваса(это даст запас по качеству отображения самого спрайта).

Так же можешь поиграться настройками отображения канваса - Render Mode. Возможно это тоже повлияет на то, что ты хочешь получить.